# Searching for PO Boxes Using the Geocoder API

Tags: here-api

I need to validate whether or not an address is a PO Box using the Geocoder API, and was thinking that the `PostalCodeType` result would provide me with the info, but it seems that supplying PO Box addresses returns different results.

For example, the following query is for a real-world PO Box:

```
?app_id={appId}&app_code={appCode}&country=USA&state=WA&searchtext=PO%20Box%20871570%20Vancouver%20WA%2098687&locationattributes=ar,mr,mv,dt,sd,ad,ai,li,in,tz,nb,rn&additionaldata=PreserveUnitDesignators,true
```

My expected output would be something along the lines of this:

```
...
"Address": {
    "Label": "PO Box 871570, Vancouver, WA, United States",
    "Country": "USA",
    "State": "WA",
    "County": "Clark",
    "City": "Vancouver",
    "PostalCode": "98687",
    "AdditionalData": [
        {
            "value": "United States",
            "key": "CountryName"
        },
        {
            "value": "Washington",
            "key": "StateName"
        },
        {
            "value": "Clark",
            "key": "CountyName"
        },
        {
            "value": "P",
            "key": "PostalCodeType"
        }
    ]
}
...
```

However, I am getting this result, for a different postal code, without the PO Box info, and the `PostalCodeType` of `N` instead of `P`

```
...
"Address": {
    "Label": "Vancouver, WA, United States",
    "Country": "USA",
    "State": "WA",
    "County": "Clark",
    "City": "Vancouver",
    "PostalCode": "98660",
    "AdditionalData": [
        {
            "value": "United States",
            "key": "CountryName"
        },
        {
            "value": "Washington",
            "key": "StateName"
        },
        {
            "value": "Clark",
            "key": "CountyName"
        },
        {
            "value": "N",
            "key": "PostalCodeType"
        }
    ]
}
...
```

Is there a better way to search PO Boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder "PostalCodeType" parameter
for the USA, the Geocoder result shows supplementary information that describes the type of the 5-Digit ZIP, as according to the USPS. The values are as follows:

"N" = Non-Unique
"M" = Military
"P" = PO Box
"U" = Unique Zip

If you looking only for "P" value, then you can filter the JSON response at your end. Filtering additionalData, based upon postalCodeType is not feasible.

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxx&country=USA&state=WA&searchtext=PO%20Box%20871570%20Vancouver%20WA%2098687&locationattributes=ar,mr,mv,dt,sd,ad,ai,li,in,tz,nb,rn&additionaldata=PreserveUnitDesignators,true&addressattributes=pst

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I'm not looking to filter the additionalData. I'm only getting one result back, and it isn't for the PO Box address that I supplied. Based on the supplied address, I would expect the PostalCodeType to equal "P" as the address is a PO Box. Is there a better way to query that address, or another method to determining if an address is a PO Box or not?